# Is it possible to programatically add an interceptor before a VM endpoint from within a Mule FunctionalTestCase? If so, how?

Tags: mule

I have a flow with two VM endpoints both configured with the exchange pattern of request/response.  I want to evaluate the message at the end of the flow when it reaches the seecond VM endpoint, before the next flow takes off with the message.  I thought I might be able to do this with an interceptor inserted before the VM endpoint.  Is this possible from within a Mule FunctionalTestCase?  Is it possible to programatically add an interceptor to a flow at all..?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think that the flows should not really be altered during the testings. In that case you would have another (although just slightly different) version running when you deploy it to a server.

Instead, I would argue that you divide your flows into testable parts and put the endpoint addresses into separate configuration. That way you can test each vm-based flow separated from each other and verify the behaviour using mock flows or similar.

```
vm://in-flow1 -> process -> vm://mock
vm://mock -> verify payload -> vm://in-flow2
```

In the "real" configuration, you change "mock" to something pointing to the second vm flow.

You can also elaborate on mocking the first or second VM flows entirely from each other to create distinct unit tests.

However, if you really want to go down the "modify code for testing purposes" rabbit hole, you can likely use some aspect oriented black magic to achieve that.

Look at [this blogpost](http://ricston.com/blog/mulespringaop/) how it's done in mule.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with Munit, and run an spy around the flow (it should work). So you can run assertions after the flow execution

https://github.com/mulesoft/munit